# How can we import data coming another erp?

Tags: erp

I have a question concerning the impact of companies acquisition and its impact on the global
information system harmonization. as an example, let's take a company A using ABS ERP
and acquiring:
- Company B using Blue cherry ERP 
- Company C using Styleman ERP

How can we harmonize and give company A real time access to data from it's affiliates ERPs?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use ETL to move data from one database to another, and have the same schema but this would be an overkill.

Another option would be to create services which sit on top of one ERP to extract data, and then custom development would be required to be done to the other system to integrate to these services. When data is viewed, data would be picked up from one of the ERP's database, and from the web services of the other.

Or else try to merge the companies using the same system, having a period of time with the systems running in parallel on both systems to make sure everything is running smoothly. Cross checks would need to be done to make sure data is OK.